# How to ask my boss to switch from a fixed-term to a remote working position?

Tags: communication, career-switch

I am working in this company for almost a year, and I am a web developer.

First they hired me because they needed someone working with embedded software (a totally different branch in ICT) but then I was kept doing webdev and recently my boss asked me to rebuild the site after having done a contact management web app.

But I have a big problem; there is a giant lack of communication in the company since I stay all the day in front of the PC alone, having nothing to share but some words with the marketing guy making useless reports just for having talks, and this is getting pretty annoying; coming in the company without even having meetings (the last I had was 1 month ago!), coming here everyday with my bicycle risking crashes because i live in a very big city with high traffic (I had 2 incidents in a month even if I always pay attention) just to stay in front of my PC in my office alone for 8 hours, is not working at all.

First of all the stress makes me less productive; then, the job I should do I can do it also on my home. My boss doesn't come to check if I am doing my work; he trusts me, or maybe he doesn't really care, but that's the deal. And I have 2 hours of lunch break, that will stick me in the company for almost 10 hours a day, having to prepare food from the day before but having in the end little time to do something good.

So, for me this is the perfect case to change my position to a remote working position; it will represent less costs for me, for the company, less stress and work/life balance for me and so more productivity that leads to stuff being done and well for them.
Yes for sure if they need me for something here, I could come in an instant, but it never happened they needed me so urgently that they have to keep me in the company, and usually the deadlines spans naturally over days if not weeks!

The only reason they could keep me here is if i should work with the machines, but this seem not happening at all (actually they need a webdev).

So, this is my position; there is a very high chance that my boss doesn't know about Smart Working (aka remote) since it's a law that here in Italy has been introduced recently (February 2016 after my employment), but even if he knows there's still a chance that he will allow me to do since he asked me in the past "*if i were about to make freelancing in my ideas*", maybe for less costs for them i don't know;

The problem is: **I don't really know how to ask.**

For me is not really clear if in November (when my contract will end) I will see another contract of employment; i don't even know if my boss did a wrong choice or he's just waiting for something. Or he's just keeping me as a resource to use in other plans in his head.
When I try to ask for more he usually delays conversations, seeming busy with working on machines first and related fields. I actually feel just like an extension of the marketing office, but i don't feel part of the company, and maybe this is all related with a "*I will not employ you again*" attitude that I don't know since this is my first job.

So how can i ask this thing? I want to change my position, but I don't know how and **if** I could.

Comment: He doesn't know maybe what that means; not that easy!

Comment: Yes but i don't think is really professional to tell my boss how to employ his workers...

Comment: Actually an answer has been given, i am not ranting or being bored, don't take it as an offense but sometimes answers are just not that simple to give, and perhaps i guess you're having a really umpleasant journey since i didin't tell you anything but.
I had luck though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40494/discussion-between-markwuji-and-joe-strazzere).

Comment: See past questions about working from home. There are definite costs to your career in doing so, to balance the advantages. I'm being hit with one of those myself at the moment -- working remotely kept me from hearing about some changes happening in the project in time to make appropriate plans to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what the boss wants, you should do. So if he wants to come in everyday, then yes, you should do that. So be prepared.

> So, for me this is the perfect case to change my position to a remote
>   working position; it will represent less costs for me, for the
>   company, less stress and work/life balance for me and so more
>   productivity that leads to stuff being done and well for them.

What is in it for your boss? Can you back these points up?
When you are sitting at home, will you equally or more productive, and can he verify that?

The point is trust.

I would setup a meeting and sit down with the boss talking about the current way of working. Tell that you see less involvement in day to day work and if it is possible to work at home time to time.

Maybe once a week and build that up.

You say you will be more productive at home, are you sure? Have you tried it? For example if you are working on a less optimal working place (chair/desk/hardware), or have a child running around, than you are maybe optimistic.

No boss will let you work from full time at the office, to full time at home. 
You should ask for an opportunity to try it out. Report the day before what you will do, and the day after how it went.

Comment: Really nice answer. It fits to be what i was looking for; especially the "Maybe once a week and build that up."
You are right, i must build this thing on trust, that's the keystone of the problem.
And yes, at home i feel really confortable, the thing is that i am more productive in the night and also that i always get sleepy after lunch and i need some rest before going back to work; if i am at home i can do that!
But for the rest i already work at home and feel really confortable at it, it is extremely relaxing ^^